# 'Unknown column' in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering, regression

I am working on an economical research and have a data frame filled with regression coefficients using `melt & tidy` functions from `broom` package. My df:

```
    > head(LmModGDP, 10)
       Country            variable        term      estimate    std.error statistic      p.value
1  Netherlands   FDI_InFlow_MilUSD (Intercept)  5.354083e+02 5.974760e+01  8.961167 1.976417e-09
2  Netherlands   FDI_InFlow_MilUSD       value  2.400677e-03 1.409779e-03  1.702875 1.005189e-01
3  Netherlands  FDI_InFlow_percGDP (Intercept)  6.184273e+02 6.723554e+01  9.197923 1.173719e-09
4  Netherlands  FDI_InFlow_percGDP       value -1.261933e+00 1.008740e+01 -0.125100 9.014067e-01
5  Netherlands  FDI_InStock_MilUSD (Intercept)  3.110956e+02 2.719577e+01 11.439116 1.201802e-11
6  Netherlands  FDI_InStock_MilUSD       value  7.025298e-04 5.307147e-05 13.237429 4.620706e-13
7  Netherlands  FDI_OutFlow_MilUSD (Intercept)  5.106762e+02 5.939921e+01  8.597356 4.465840e-09
8  Netherlands  FDI_OutFlow_MilUSD       value  1.920313e-03 8.646908e-04  2.220808 3.528536e-02
9  Netherlands FDI_OutFlow_percGDP (Intercept)  2.593453e+02 5.334202e+01  4.861932 4.838082e-05
10 Netherlands FDI_OutFlow_percGDP       value  3.931491e+00 5.332541e-01  7.372641 7.896681e-08
```

After I filter the df using any method (even simply by subseting or with `dplyr` package):

```
LmModGDP[LmModGDP$variable == "FDI_InStock_MilUSD",]
```

or

```
LmModGDP %>%
  filter(variable == "FDI_InStock_MilUSD")
```

It returns the desired df but when I drag my mouse over the last column (`p.value`) in RStudio viewer it tells me that it is "Unknown Column" and the data still correct. Also when I use `str` or `class` function on it it shows that it is numeric but in the viewer it shows something else..

My desired df:

```
    Country           variable        term     estimate    std.error statistic      p.value
5  Netherlands FDI_InStock_MilUSD (Intercept) 3.110956e+02 2.719577e+01 11.439116 1.201802e-11
6  Netherlands FDI_InStock_MilUSD       value 7.025298e-04 5.307147e-05 13.237429 4.620706e-13
19     Romania FDI_InStock_MilUSD (Intercept) 3.122229e+01 3.313134e+00  9.423796 7.188216e-10
20     Romania FDI_InStock_MilUSD       value 2.128223e-03 7.035679e-05 30.249006 8.588104e-22
```

When I try to use `kable` function to display it in markdown report `p.value` column shows only 0 values... not the actual ones.

Can someone help me ?

!! UP !!

Here's an output of `str` :

```
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 28 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Country  : chr  "Netherlands" "Netherlands" "Netherlands" "Netherlands" ...
 $ variable : Factor w/ 7 levels "FDI_InFlow_MilUSD",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
 $ term     : chr  "(Intercept)" "value" "(Intercept)" "value" ...
 $ estimate : num  535.4083 0.0024 618.4273 -1.2619 311.0956 ...
 $ std.error: num  59.7476 0.00141 67.23554 10.0874 27.19577 ...
 $ statistic: num  8.961 1.703 9.198 -0.125 11.439 ...
 $ p.value  : num  1.98e-09 1.01e-01 1.17e-09 9.01e-01 1.20e-11 ...
 - attr(*, "vars")= chr  "Country" "variable"
 - attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "indices")=List of 14
  ..$ : int  0 1
  ..$ : int  2 3
  ..$ : int  4 5
  ..$ : int  6 7
  ..$ : int  8 9
  ..$ : int  10 11
  ..$ : int  12 13
  ..$ : int  14 15
  ..$ : int  16 17
  ..$ : int  18 19
  ..$ : int  20 21
  ..$ : int  22 23
  ..$ : int  24 25
  ..$ : int  26 27
 - attr(*, "group_sizes")= int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 - attr(*, "biggest_group_size")= int 2
 - attr(*, "labels")='data.frame':  14 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Country : chr  "Netherlands" "Netherlands" "Netherlands" "Netherlands" ...
  ..$ variable: Factor w/ 7 levels "FDI_InFlow_MilUSD",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "vars")= chr  "Country" "variable"
  ..- attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it on a fresh session?

Comment: It is also likely showing zero due to rounding - your pvalues are very small

Comment: @akrun  sorry, I am not so familiarized with all the terms, what you mean by reproducing it on a fresh session ?

Comment: I meant if you restart the Rstudio and do this again

Comment: @user20650      if it would be because of rounding then it should print atleast few digits..

Comment: @akrun already done that

Comment: @RazvanCretu ; in your example at the end, your pvalues are all less than 1e-10, (0.0000000001), hence why zero is shown (I assume that kable does some rounding). An easy way to get it to print as is is to set the column to character -- but most often this level of detail on pvalues is not required.

Comment: @user20650  The column, as I've told, in the first example I shown it is storred as numeric but just after I apply a filtering or subseting method it stores it as an "Unknown column" and can't work with it anymore.. I will try to print it as character

Comment: @user20650 regarding your assumption.. You were right, `kable` does some rounding. It even has an argument `digits` where you can specify the number of digits to round to. Also regarding my problem I've found that I can work perfectly fine with that column even though its class appear "Unknown column" in RStudio viewer, but when I run `class` it tells me that is numeric, it kinda seem like a RStudio bug

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, this is why I write here an answer.

Could you show us the output of str(LmModGDP) ? Maybe the df is nested? Maybe it is not a pure df but has special properties. Have you tried forcing  LmModGDP<-as.data.frame(LmModGDP) ?

Have you tried forcing LmModGDP$p.value<-as.numeric(LmModGDP$p.value) ?

Have you tried converting to data.table and see if the behavior is different after applying your filter on it?

UPDATE1:
Thanks for posting the str(). Your object is a "grouped_df". Have you tried ungroup(LmModGDP)?

Comment: I will post an output in the next couple of hours just to get back at my pc. I've tried convertig it to data.frame and even coercing the column to numeric and still nothing.. I do have to try converting to data.table.  P.S LmModGDP is a tibble

Comment: I've came up with an output of `str` function. Check out for the edit. Sorry for such a late response